# Is there a Twitter version of the Facebook Comments social plugin?

Tags: gratis, facebook, twitter

My aim is to add commenting functionality to my website. The [Facebook Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments) social plugin does exactly what I need except I need a Twitter version which lets users comment with their Twitter ID instead of their Facebook ID.

Is there a Twitter version of the Facebook Comments social plugin?

Comment: Are you looking for a WordPress plugin, or something you can add to a custom HTML page, or something else?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: What kind of website do you need to use it on?  Is it WordPress, Joomla, something you put together yourself in Dreamweaver, or something else?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. It's a WordPress website but the solution doesn't necessarily have to be a WordPress plugin.

Answer (score 1):

So far, I didn't know that **Twitter** has the **API comments** like Facebook.

**Twitter** has *third-party* application that allow for registered user using them account for register/login on the trusted application/web application. For example, Using **Twitter ID** for **log in** the Stackexchange sites. Since I don't know the Twitter API comments service, I would like to give you another **API comments** suggestion which your audience can use their **Twitter ID** for commenting in your web apps, blog, and soon. Here's below:

1. **Livefyre**

   > **[Livefyre](http://web.livefyre.com)** (product name: **Community Comments**). *Livefyre Community Comments* replaces your default comments with real-time conversations. Our social integration features make it easy to capture all the conversations going on about your posts across Twitter and Facebook, and pull your friends into the conversation.. (from: [Community Comments from Livefyre](http://web.livefyre.com/comments)).

   It's **free**. Then, there were many features you can get, here's below:

   - Admin dashboard
   - Explore Community Comments Features
2. **Disqus**

   > **[Disqus](https://disqus.com)** is a **free service** that enables great online communities. As the web’s most popular discussion
   >   system, Disqus is used by millions of websites that cover pretty
   >   much any topic imaginable. Our magic is in connecting people to
   >   stuff worth talking about. (from: [about
   >   Disqus](https://disqus.com/about/)).

   Disqus is **free** to use and works with virtually any type of
   website and you can easily import all your existing comments. The
   features:

   - Easy to add anywhere, Wordpress, Tumblr, Blogger, and more.
   - Import existing content and export anytime you would like.
   - Simple and quick configuration.
   - Adapts with your website's design and colors.
   - You can use social community API for commenting, like **Twitter ID**
   - [more](https://disqus.com/websites/)...

There are still plenty of services like that. It's possible, not only developer but also community develop the vanilla of Twitter API for next commenting services.